# How to split a multi-leveled array by a specific format

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array as below

```
#bad
tourney = [
  [
    [["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"]],      
    [["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"]]
  ],
  [
    [["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"]],
    [["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]]
  ]
]
```

and I have to implement a recursive tournament method that places each of the competitors against one another. This tournament has to increase to any number as long as it's 2^n. Is there any array method that will separate this array into two levels like the array below?

```
#good
tourney = [
  ["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"],
  ["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"],
  ["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"],
  ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]
]
```

With this, I could use `each_slice(2)` to place opponents against one another.

---

#### Solved

Below is what I was able to come up.

```
def split(array)
  return array.flatten(1)
end

def depth_array(a)
  return 0 unless a.is_a?(Array)
  return 1+depth_array(a[0])
end

def format_array(array)
  good = array
  while depth_array(good) > 2
    good = split(good)
  end
end

tourney = [[[["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"]],      

       [["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"]]],

       [[["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"]],

       [["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]]]]

tourney2 = [[["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"]], 

        [["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"]]]

tourney3 = [["Omer", "P"], ["Allen", "S"]]

tourney4 = [[[[["Armando", "P"], ["Armando", "P"]], [["Armando", "P"], ["Armando", "P"]]], 

         [[["Allen", "S"], ["Allen", "S"]], [["Allen", "S"], ["Allen", "S"]]]], 

         [[[["Dave", "S"], ["Dave", "S"]], [["Dave", "S"], ["Dave", "S"]]], 

          [[["David E.", "R"], ["David E.", "R"]], [["David E.", "R"], ["David E.", "R"]]]]]



format_array(tourney4)
```

Comment: are you looking for `Array#flatten` http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten?  ... it might take it too far (too flat) but it might put you on the right track.

Comment: Seems like a case of "primitive" obsession. If the "lowest level" pairs were objects (ie ["Allen", "S"] was an object other than an array), then flatten would be the simplest

Answer (score 2):

`tourney.flatten(2)` turns the bad array into the good array.

Comment: I will try this, but I might have to be able to do the same thing if say the tournament had 16 people in it, and it would be setup the same way. So more layers I would have to deal with.

Comment: Since I had to be able to take any number of competitors to the power of 2, I decided it would be best to just flatten(1) until the depth of the array was equal to 2 which is the the required depth I needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
tourney = [[[["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"]],      
           [["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"]]],
           [[["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"]],
           [["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]]]]

good = [].tap do |arr|
  tourney.flatten.each_slice(2) do |pr|
    arr << pr
  end
end

puts good.inspect

# output 
[["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"], ["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"], ["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"], ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]]
```